# How long does oil last for the sword and shield?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter Generations,  a new concept was introduced to the sword and shield wepons which was oil. I've been using it quite a bit, but the one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how long the oil effects last. It seems it is much shorter than cool and warm drinks.  How long do oil effects last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the oils is roughly 2 minutes.